# What determines your character's voice actor in TOR?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I started up a Human Republic Commando in TOR, and was delighted to be greeted with the delightful sound of [Jennifer Hale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRHG0.jpg).

So when I had the chance to make another Human character, I jumped at the chance, confidant [Jennifer Hale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRHG0.jpg) would make just as lovely a Smuggler as she did Commando.

...Except, my human smuggler didn't sound like Ms. Hale, as expected.

So my question: What determines the voice actor/actress for your character? It doesn't appear to be based on race - is it based on class? Body type? Something else entirely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [imdb voice actor credits](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1320395/fullcredits#cast) I would say each base class and sex combination determines the voice actor

Comment: The voice actor is the predominant reason I chose my Jedi Knight. I was disappointed that David Hayter did not employ more gruff-speak.